# ActionMailer responds with "501 5.5.4 Invalid argument"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, ruby-on-rails-4, mailgun

I'm working on an application with Rails 4 on Ruby 2.0.0. The application sends out an email after a registration in Devise.

This is the code that sends the email:

app/models/sponsor.rb:

```
after_create :send_email_to_admin

private

def send_email_to_admin
    AdminMailer.new_sponsor_email(self).deliver
end
```

app/mailers/admin_mailer.rb

```
class AdminMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default to: '**removed**'

  def new_sponsor_email(sponsor)
    @sponsor = sponsor
    p @sponsor
    mail(subject: "New Sponsor Registration")
  end
end
```

And this is the generated email from the log file:

```
Sent mail to **removed** (725.5ms)
Date: Mon, 02 Sep 2013 15:01:03 -0400
From: **removed**
To: **removed**
Message-ID: <5224e06f4dddd_2e5a3fa0452dcfd874597@centaur.mail>
Subject: New Sponsor Registration
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
 boundary="--==_mimepart_5224e06f4cca1_2e5a3fa0452dcfd87441a";
 charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit


----==_mimepart_5224e06f4cca1_2e5a3fa0452dcfd87441a
Content-Type: text/plain;
 charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

A new sponsor has signed up!
==========================

----==_mimepart_5224e06f4cca1_2e5a3fa0452dcfd87441a
Content-Type: text/html;
 charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
  <head>
    <meta content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' http-equiv='Content-Type'>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>A new sponsor has signed up!</h1>
  </body>
</html>

----==_mimepart_5224e06f4cca1_2e5a3fa0452dcfd87441a--
```

when I try to test the code by creating a sponsor, I just get this error:

```
Net::SMTPSyntaxError in Devise::RegistrationsController#create
501 5.5.4 Invalid argument
```

My understanding is that this is typically because the email is and invalid email, but all of my emails are very simple, in the format of `name@domain.tld` and `no-reply@domain.tld`.

Comment: As a note, it seems that the code works fine if I switch to connecting to Gmail for SMTP. I'm trying to setup the app to use Mailgun with SMTP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue seemed to be that I was using "domain" in my smtp_settings. When I removed that, I was able to send emails from both Mailgun and Gmail

Comment: Where is this domain and how to remove it ??