# Devise confirmation mails ending SMTPSyntaxError Invalid Argument (501 5.5.4)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, mailgun

Long story short:

This are my productions smtp_settings:

```
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'myapp.herokuapp.com' }
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  # SMTP settings for mailgun
  ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
    port:           587,
    address:        'smtp.mailgun.org',
    domain:         ENV['ms_domain'], #Domain name
    user_name:      ENV['ms_username'], #Default SMTP Login
    password:       ENV['ms_pass'], #Default Password
    authentication: :plain
  }
```

And this is my devise config.mail_sender in devise.rb:

```
  config.mailer_sender = '"Kazik" <kask@wp.pl>'
```

And the error is:

```
Net::SMTPSyntaxError (501 5.5.4 Invalid argument
```

I have googled for some time, found some answers but none give me green light.

I tried to remove the [domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18579439/actionmailer-responds-with-501-5-5-4-invalid-argument) from smtp_settings, but I ended up with, different error >> `Net::SMTPFatalError (550 5.7.1 Relaying denied`, and after I googled for it. I think that it is an authentication error so I left the domain.

I also thought that my mail_sender is wrong but according to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9712916/how-to-setup-devise-sender-name-for-email) it seem legit.

I also look many other pages but with none success. This is something I`m doing for the first time so, error is probably something trivial. But the error output gives me to little info to handle it my self.

Answer (score 0):

try `config.mailer_sender = "Kazik <kask@wp.pl>"`

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#sending-email-with-name

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment yet, but I believe the 587 needs quotes. So it should read:

```
port: "587",
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry I put this as an answer, but I can't comment yet.

I had the same problem in Rails 2.3 with Mailgun. Removing the domain setting and making sure all settings were strings (including the port, which is the one I had as an integer) solved it for me.